# How to get Selected Index JQuery Mobile Listview

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

New Bie : I have a list data that get from database using json `format` and display into listview. But i still confuse how to get the selected index of the listview, this is my code :

```
<script>
    function loadListTips(){
    $('#message').html('Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "http://10.0.2.2/compfest/ajax/belajar/list_tips.php",
        success: function(response){
            var html = '';
            $.each(response, function(index,item){
                html += '<li>';
                html += '<a>';
                html += '<span class="judul">' + item.judul + '</span>';
                html += '</a>';
                html += '</li>';
            });
            $('#penyakit_list').html(html);
            $('#penyakit_list').listview('refresh');
            $('#message').html('');
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Hope there is someone help me.

Comment: "selected index of the listview" - what do u mean by that? are u trying to write a `click` event for the `a` tag in listview?

Comment: yes , i want to try how to write a click event for the listview based on index ..

Comment: any need for the use of index? actually its kinda unwanted..why do u need index?

Comment: Because the index value will send to the server via Ajax. And the server will process the request based on index. Thanks for your answer .

Comment: thank's but still confuse, would you mind if you write complete code please. .

Comment: Thanks a lot , now is working using  .live click, on JQuery 1.6.4 , the difference version has get effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need selected index of the `li` to bind the `click` event. You could try using event delegation to bind your click events. Bind the click event to the `ul` and delegate it to `li`.

```
$("#penyakit_list").on("click", "li a", function() {
  //your code
});
```

One more option would be to bind the click to the `document` :

```
$(document).on("click", "#penyakit_list li a", function() {
  //your code
});
```

To access the index, just use this inside the click event :

```
$(this).closest("li").index();
```

where `this` is the `a` you just clicked. So now your click event would look like this :

```
$(document).on("click", "#penyakit_list li a", function() {
      alert($(this).closest("li").index()); // this will give the index of the li. You could store it in a variable and send it via ajax.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 goes to bundleofjoy!

I can't add a comment because my "reputation point" below the limit value to add comment.

I used this answer as `alert($(this).closest("li").attr("id"));`

Have a good day!